# ASP.NET using Eval to get page / file name

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I set the text value of a hyperlink to a the page or image name within a databound url string. Something like:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("attachUrl")%>' Text="<%# System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Eval("attachUrl"))%>"></asp:HyperLink>
```

The NavigateURL works but not the Text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you break the string when you add the `"` in the `Eval` method. Use apostrophe's on the outer text so you can use double-quotes for the `Eval` method i.e.

```
Text='<%# System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Eval("attachUrl").ToString())%>'
```

Comment: Thanks, but still no joy. I get a 'Compilation Error'.

Comment: Ah, it works now. Needed to add a ToString() to the eval. Thanks for the help.